# Optimal scheduling and placement of embarrassingly parallel job

Tags: openmp, scheduling, numactl

I'm trying to optimize run time of an embarrassingly parallel code.  I'm hoping there is something out there that can do this already and I just didn't see it in my searches.

Info...

- The code is embarrassingly parallel
- There are 100 runs overall, and I would like to be able to run 20 instances concurrently
- Runtime and RAM requirements scale ~linearly from job 1 (5 hours, 20GB) to 100 (10 hours, 30GB)
- Individual instances of the code use threaded GEMM calls (currently Intel MKL, 2 threads per job)
- The computer has 2 NUMA nodes (Dual socket system)
- I am restricted on the amount of RAM (I cannot do all of the higher memory runs at one time)
- Currently some jobs cross over between NUMA nodes and slow everything to a crawl

How can I optimally schedule these jobs in terms of time/RAM placement in a NUMA aware fashion?  Is there a script or scheduling system that can handle doing this already or would I need to roll my own?

I feel like I have more questions about implementing this, but I think it will just make it more confusing.

Comment: Setting `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` should be enough to make your jobs stay in place.

Comment: [Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/overview.html) can handle job allocations restricted by memory and it would also handle the binding of jobs to NUMA nodes. But setting this up for a single workstation sounds a bit overkill unless this is a permanent setup

Comment: I tried omp_proc_bind but I didn't seem to behave correctly.  I actually don't think I was able to set it to true.   Any time I set true it would say spread in verbose output.

Comment: @Homer512 I was hoping there was something short of slurm/pbs that could accomplish this.  Right now I just work inwards from the ends of the list using xargs

Comment: What would be wrong with `omp_set_num_threads` in the code ?

Comment: @PierU I'm using a bash script to manage the runs and setting OMP_NUM_THREADS env var there.

Comment: I cobbled together some code to submit each job to the numa node with the fewest runs on it using numactl.  At a glance it seems to be running a little faster.  I'll have to wait until tomorrow evening to see.

Comment: I feel like the problem child function is cgetrs for me in the intel MKL.  It gets called a few hundred times with a single RHS.  The way the code is structured it would not be easy to combine the calls.  I think the repeated calls is really where there is a huge penalty on jobs getting split across NUMA nodes.  I've seen calls that normally take 200ms take 1000 seconds.  With the NUMA aware code I mentioned above I don't seem to be running into this issue.

Comment: I can't see what would prevent using `omp_set_num_threads` even in your case, regardless OMP_NUM_THREADS

Comment: @PierU what is the difference between setting it in the code vs using the environment variable?

Comment: I thinks it's equivalent, and `omp_set_num_threads()` will overide `OMP_NUM_THREADS`

Comment: @pieru not seeing what this would buy me over just using the environment variable up front.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I have made a confusion between your question and another question ! Please ignore all my comments !